# Select n objects from collection based on ranked value

Tags: c#, .net, collections

```
public class A
{
   public int x { get; set; }
}
```

Then somewhere, a collection:

```
public List<A> aList { get; set; }
```

Now, how to select n objects of this list based on highest x values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about with LINQ:

```
var bestAs = aList.OrderByDescending(a => a.x).Take(n);
```

Comment: Presuming this is not the OP's case; Would you use that approach if `aList` contained 1M items?